# Entity Framework (MySQL) - move data from one database to another using two dbcontexts

Tags: mysql, .net, entity-framework

Using Entity Framework 6 and MySQL, I am trying to archive data from a 'production' database table to an 'archive' database. I have created two DBContexts one for each database. Each database has the same schema.

I can move an entire table of data from the production database to the archive database using the following code:

```
using (MyDBContext archiveContext = 
MyDBContext.CreateEntitiesForSpecificDatabaseName("archive_db"))
using (MyDBContext prodContext = 
MyDBContext.CreateEntitiesForSpecificDatabaseName("prod_db"))
{
    if(prodContext.myTable.Any())
    {
        archiveContext.myTable.AddRange(prodContext.myTable.AsNoTracking());
        archiveContext.SaveChanges();
    }  
}
```

However I don't want to archive the whole table, I only wish to archive data older than a certain date, so I tried the following:

```
using (MyDBContext archiveContext = 
MyDBContext.CreateEntitiesForSpecificDatabaseName("archive_db"))
using (MyDBContext prodContext = 
MyDBContext.CreateEntitiesForSpecificDatabaseName("prod_db"))
{
    IQueryable<myTable> dataToArchive =
      from mt in prodContext.myTable
      where mt.date < DateTimeSixMonths
      select mt;

     archiveContext.myTable.AddRange(dataToArchive);
     archiveContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

but I cannot get around the exception I get when I run this:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'An entity object cannot be
>   referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.'

It occurs on this line:

```
archiveContext.myTable.AddRange(dataToArchive);
```

Is it possible to somehow remove the tracking from the 'dataToArchive'

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried disposing the first DataContext after retrieving data? Something like this:

```
List<myTable> dataToArchive;

using (MyDBContext prodContext = 
        MyDBContext.CreateEntitiesForSpecificDatabaseName("prod_db"))
{

    dataToArchive = (from mt in prodContext.myTable
        where mt.date < DateTimeSixMonths
        select mt).ToList();
}

using (MyDBContext archiveContext = 
    MyDBContext.CreateEntitiesForSpecificDatabaseName("archive_db"))
{
    archiveContext.myTable.AddRange(dataToArchive);
    archiveContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, disposing the first DataContext also prevents the IEntityChangeTracker exception and allows the insertions into the archive table, but I still had the same issue with new primary keys being created, so decided not to use 2 DBContexts in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Using EF to manage archiving data isn't ideal, something like that would be better served at the database level using insert-select + delete for low to moderate data volumes or detachable partitions (I.e. 3-6 mo. partition sizes) that can be moved between databases.

To do this with EF (only recommended for small and non-complex domain models) you should be able to accomplish this by disabling the proxy generation in your read context, load the data `AsNoTracking`, then add it to the new context DbSet. This example does not handle associated entities, or do the delete from the prod DbSet.

```
using (MyDBContext prodContext = 
        MyDBContext.CreateEntitiesForSpecificDatabaseName("prod_db"))
{
    prodContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    dataToArchive = prodContext.myTable.AsNoTracking()
        .Where(mt => mt.Date < DateTimeSixMonths);


    using (MyDBContext archiveContext = 
        MyDBContext.CreateEntitiesForSpecificDatabaseName("archive_db"))
    {
        archiveContext.myTable.AddRange(dataToArchive);
        archiveContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for suggesting an alternative to EF. I was starting to think the EF approach was over-complicating things but it seemed like something that should be possible. The above suggestion regarding disabling proxy generation worked, but then I ran into an issue with the insertions into the archive database having new primary keys and not being exact archives of the production table. I reverted to a simpler archiving solution using insert select and delete.

Comment: yeah, to get around that with your archive DB would need to be set up without the identity/default value, then you would need to use an entity definitions with DatabaseGeneratedOption set to None. This may mean 2x entity definitions and/or dedicated DbContext for prod to serve the archive process. More of a mess than it's probably worth. :)